# How can I know if there is a data from server in socket?

Tags: uwp

I am coding a project of socket client.

The server does not make by us and it will send data to the client at times.

So that I have to use a looping task to check if there is a data always.

As we know, by using the read command of the socket without there actually is a data receive, the socket will halt.

In WinForm, I used the `Socket.Available` to check if there actually is a data receive then read the data.

However, in UWP it seems has not the `Available` property. I used the code to receive data in UWP as below:

```
Stream streamIn = Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();                        
streamIn.Flush();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
string ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
```

But as I said above, the code runs without there actually is a data receive, the socket of UWP will halt as Winform.

How can I solve this problem, or there is a new property can replace the `Available` of winform? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, you could use [StreamSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226882) connection and create a background task with the [SocketActivityTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn806009). The SocketActivityTrigger will activate the background task when a packet is received.

More information, please see [Network communications in the background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background).

Here's a [Socket activity trigger stream socket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket) for your reference.